# Ungreedy regex matching in sublime text 2

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'm fairly familiar with regex, but it seems I'm not so good at doing regex in sublime text 2, what I thought should work seems to match but too greedily.

I have a file with lots of `mv` commands in it like the one below, and I wanting add an additional command above it to create the directory where the file is to be moved to. So for the below example the `mkdir` command would be `mkdir --parents --verbose '/path/to/dir2';`

`mv --no-clobber --verbose '/path/to/dir1/file1.zip' '/path/to/dir2/file2.zip';`

I tried this regex which I was sure would be perfectly fine, but it matches the whole line and not just the sections I would like to match.

Sublime regex search

```
mv --no-clobber --verbose '(.*?).zip' '(.*?)/(.*?).zip';
```

Sublime regex replace

```
mkdir --parents --verbose '$2';
mv --no-clobber --verbose '$1.zip' '$2\/$3.zip';
```

Edit: Just to clarify the first `(.*?)` matches the whole line, the subsequent `(.*?)` match nothing.

Comment: Use `mv --no-clobber --verbose '([^']*)' '([^']*)/([^']*)';`

Answer (score 0):

You have few unwanted capture groups and there is no need to use `.*?`.

You can search using this regex:

```bash
mv --no-clobber --verbose '[^']+' '(.+)/[^/.]+\.zip';
```

and replace using:

```bash
$0\nmkdir --parents --verbose '$1';
```

Here `$0` is back-reference for the full match of `mv` command.

**Output:**

```bash
mv --no-clobber --verbose '/path/to/dir1/file1.zip' '/path/to/dir2/files2.zip';
mkdir --parents --verbose '/path/to/dir2';
```

---

You can also search using `\K` (match reset):

```bash
mv --no-clobber --verbose '[^']+' '(.+)/[^/.]+\.zip';\K
```

and replace with:

```bash
\nmkdir --parents --verbose '$1';
```